# Get User statistics in NodeWebkit App

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js, node-webkit, usage-statistics

I am using `NodeWebKIT` for a desktop application with AngularJS front-end and using `SailsJS` in backend.

In app, currently user can chat, create some documents and add comments on it.

I need to get a statistics about app like:

- How many are chatting
- How many are creating documents
- How many are active in app
- How much time are they active in app
- Who are not using app at all
- How many are viewing documents, etc

I need to log all this data and later render it in ADMIN panel so that admin can view statistics about app.
Is there any way this can be achieved?

Thanks in Advance